# I would like to find a generalization of the plane wave expansion to Hankel functions.

Tags: fourier-analysis, special-functions, fourier-series, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

The plane wave expansion is
\begin{equation}
e^{i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}=\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}i^\ell(2\ell+1)j_{\ell}(kx)P_{\ell}(\cos(\theta))
\end{equation}
where $j_\ell$ is the spherical Bessel function of order $\ell$ and $P_\ell$ is the Legendre polynomial.  I have run into a problem where it makes sense to replace $j_\ell$ in the above formula by $h_\ell$, which is the spherical Hankel function of order $\ell$ (or Neumann function, either would work).  I would like to find a simple formula for the LHS if this replacement is made.  Is anyone aware of a way of doing this, or any research that has been done on this type of generalization?